# Cursor inside another cursor in sqlite db

Tags: sqlite, cursors

I have the below code where I am using nested cursors. Both of them are not null but I am getting error 
"android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0" on the inner cursor.

```
Cursor cursor3 = null;

    Cursor cursor2 = db.getAllFriendsChat();  
    cursor2.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor2.isAfterLast()) {
           String number = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ChatModel.COLUMN_CHAT_SENT_TO));
           cursor3 = db.getName(number);
           String name   = cursor3.getString(cursor3.getColumnIndexOrThrow(db.KEY_NAME));
           db.insertList(name, number);
           cursor3.close();
           cursor2.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor2.close();
```

getName() Method:

```
public Cursor getName(String phone) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_STUDENTS + " where phone_number = " + phone, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst(); //***I see that this statement is executed.***
        }
        return c;
    }
```

I am unable to understand where I am doing mistake. Is there a different way to handle nested cursors in sqlite db. Pls help.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`rawQuery()` never returns `null`.

To test whether a cursor is empty, you have to check whether `moveToFirst()` succeeds, or call `isAfterLast()`.